# How to get post body data from java jax-rs server

Tags: java, jax-rs, multipartform-data

I followed a simple java server setup [guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-restful-web-service.html).

So i have something like this:

MyApp.java

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> h = new HashSet<>();
        h.add( HelloWorld.class );
        return h;
    }
}
```

and HelloWord.java

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Request;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorld {
    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getClichedMessage() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes()
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String doThis(String x) {
        System.out.println(x);
        //....
    }
}
```

The incoming request is of type

```
content-type = multipart/form-data; boundary=somerandstuff
```

and looks like :

```
--somerandstuff
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="somedata1"

data text 1here
--somerandstuff
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="somedata2"

more data text here

--somerandstuff
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="numberoffiles"

3
--somerandstuff
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="firstfile"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

{unreadable symbols thing here}

.
.
. 2 more files like above
```

How do I go about actually reading the data? I've tried many things and can't get it to work. I tried using `httpRequest.getParameterMap()` and `httpRequest.getParameterNames()` and printing everything but nothing prints. I can't seem to even access the post body data. The only things I can access are the headers using `httpRequest.getHeaderNames()`.

What I want to do is store each file in a File object (or something similar) and then download it. How would i go about doing that? I've looked at a few posts on this topic but when I try implementing the solutions, they don't seem to work.

Edit: here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.serverproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>serverProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>serverProject</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.6.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.31</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.31</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.31</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.31</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What JAX-RS implementation are you using? There is no standard multipart support in the JAX-RS spec, but each implementation has their own specific support for it.

Comment: I'm not sure. I followed https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-restful-web-service.html. This is my first time trying to setup a rest server with Java (I usually use nodejs) so I'm honestly not sure. I used intelij to set up the project and that used a GlassFish server.

Comment: So Glassfish uses Jersey as its JAX-RS implementation. And from the looks of the link you provided, it looks like you are using Maven as the build tool. Do you have a pom.xml file in your project? If so, can you post it.

Comment: added pom.xml file to the post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so what you have is multipart data, which is most commonly used to send multiple files and metadata (or other data) along with those files. There is no standard JAX-RS support for multipart, but you are using Jersey (a JAX-RS implementation) and Jersey *does* have support for multipart. The first thing you need to do is add a new dependency to your pom.xml file

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>2.31</version>
</dependency>
```

The next thing you need to do is register this feature with your application. Since you are using an `Application` subclass, you would add the `MultiPartFeature` class to the classes in `getClasses()`

```java
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> h = new HashSet<>();
        h.add(HelloWorld.class);
        h.add(MultiPartFeature.class);
        return h;
    }
}
```

Now we can use this feature. In your resource method, what we will do is declare each part using Jersey's `@FormDataParam` annotation. As you can see in the multipart entity, each part has a name

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="somedata1"
```

Here the name of this part is `somedata1`. So we will add a parameter for this part. Also notice I will add `@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)` as that is the content-type our method will be consuming.

```
@POST
@Path("upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response fileUpload(@FormDataParam("somedata1") String someData1) {
    ...
}
```

Based on what type of data is expected, that's how you will determine the parameter type. The type of `somedata1` is just plain text, that's why I used a String. But the `numeroffiles` part is a number, so I can use an `int` for that part

```
public Response fileUpload(@FormDataParam("somedata1") String someData1,
                           @FormDataParam("numberoffiles") int numberOfFiles) {
    ...
}
```

The `firtfile` part is going to be a binary file. So what we can use an `InputStream`, `File`, or `byte[]` parameter. We can also add an additional parameter of type `FormDataContentDisposition` which will give us some info about this file. For this example, I will use an `InputStream`. Just google "how to save an `InputStream` to a file in Java"

```
public Response fileUpload(@FormDataParam("somedata1") String someData1,
                           @FormDataParam("numberoffiles") int numberOfFiles,
                           @FormDataParam("file1") InputStream firstFile,
                           @FormDataParam("file1") FormDataContentDisposition fdcd) {
    ...
    String fileName = fdcd.getFileName();
}
```

### UPDATE

If the number of files is unknown, instead of decalring all these separate parts, what you can do is just declare one parameter of type `FormDataMultiPart` and programmatically extract each part

```java
public Response fileUpload(FormDataMultiPart multipart) {
    Map<String,List<FormDataBodyPart>> bodyParts = multipart.getFields();
    FormDataBodyPart someDataPart = multipart.getField("somedata1");
    String someData = someDataPart.getValueAs(String.class);
}
```

You will need to traverse all the `FormDataBodyPart`s and you use the `bodyPart.getValueAs(Class)` method to extract the data of the body part. For the files, you would use `getValueAs(InputStream.class)`.

And that's pretty much it. That's how you work with multipart in Jersey. For more info, you can [read the complete docs](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart)

Comment: The number of files sent from the client depends on the "numberoffiles" form data parameter. And this number can be anything greater than 1 and can vary from request to request. Is there a way to get all the files?